# How to add my ad code for google adsense?

Tags: jquery, adsense

I applied to google adsense and add code as suggested by google below the `<body>` tag. Here is my code:

```
<body class="home page page-id-5 page-parent page-template page-template-page-catagory-english page-template-page-catagory-english-php logged-in admin-bar no-customize-support">

<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- test -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:block"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-1440450516824187"
     data-ad-slot="7905678954"
     data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

But I got the following error:

> Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: have you registered your domain to the adsense program in google adsence. First you need to add your domain to the google adsense then it will take some time to approve your request.

Comment: First I create adsense account for youtube. Then I applied for my website vai this hosted account. And I added my wesite url for which I request to adsense and I got the following confirmation:

You have successfully changed your upgrade URL to www.codingpractise.com. Click here if you want to change it again.

Comment: Then you can simply create new add units from my add section with the recommended setting and place the provided codes to you website and wait for getting the adds, do read the adsense policies.

Comment: YES. I exactly did the same you suggest. But console error means there is a problem. Even In my adsense account I can see:  In order to complete your request to show ads on your own website, you need to implement the ad code on www.codingpractise.com. Your upgrade request can only be reviewed once your ad code has impressions on that domain.  


BUT MY AD CODE IS NOT WORKING.

Comment: You need to go through the adsence policies, because sometime It does not want to display ads on the domain.

Comment: the app domain error is facebook, not adsense. your adsense code looks fine, it's not showing anything because you haven't been approved yet